# Symfony 2.3 @ORM\preUpdate purpose?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working my way through the http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/extending-the-model-blog-comments.html  tutorial. In the blog and comments entity a preUpdate is declared but i don't really get their purpose eg:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setCreated(new \DateTime());
        $this->setUpdated(new \DateTime());

        $this->setApproved(true);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\preUpdate
     */
    public function setUpdatedValue()
    {
       $this->setUpdated(new \DateTime());
    }
```

What is the point in the setUpdatedValue() here if the contruct does the same job?

Also, when i run i run `$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Blogger\BlogBundle` get the error:

```
  [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                                                                  
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\preUpdate" in method Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Comment::  
  setUpdatedValue() does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

Comment: First try `@ORM\PreUpdate` instead of `@ORM\preUpdate` because it is case-sensitive

Comment: Thank you, indeed it was simply a case sensitive issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructor is called only when the entity is created, not when it is loaded from db (doctrine uses `unserialize()` for this). `setUpdatedValue()` sets the `updated` property before the entity is saved (`created` stays the same).

Comment: And I would add, just thinking about logic, it's more appropriate to make a treatment on update in a PreUpdate life cycle callback than in the entity constructor. It is meaningless to do this kind of process in constructor.